# Android Volley and the usage of Tasks or Threads in the response

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-volley, android-thread

in my App i do different requests to get the HTML code of a website. After that, the App parses the HTML, maybe another request will performed and parsed. At the end a ListView is filled with the parsed data.

Now i read that Volley runs all code in the onResponse method on the UI Thread. So maybe it is better to do the parsing in a new thread. I implemented it as follows.

```
new Thread(new HTMLSiteParsingTask(response)).start();

class HTMLSiteParsingTask implements Runnable {
  String mResponse;
  HTMLSiteParsingTask(String response) {
    mResponse = response;
  }
  public void run() {
  //do something...
  callerActivity.addData(dataHashMap);
  }
}
```

At the end of the processing i call a method of the MainActivity to add the data to the Listview "callerActivity.addData(dataHashMap);". This Method does the following:

```
runOnUiThread(new AddItemsTask(ItemList));
```

Is there a difference between AsyncTask and Thread so that i should use one of them? Or doesn't matter? Is there maybe a better way to do that stuff?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a [custom request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html). Place your parsing logic in the `parseNetworkResponse` method - it will be called by Volley from a worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTaks are best suited for short bursts of work as recommended by google themselves. This way gives you easy way to access the ui thread directly. The con is that it's very and i repeat very poorly tired to the activity or fragment calling it. Also if you need to inform the activity directly, you'll have to either pass a reference of the activity (which can lead to memory leaks ) or use methods like event bus or a broadcast receiver.

If you do decide to pass the activity for the easy approach, make sure to have it inside a WeakReference and have checks if nullity, isFinishing and isDestroyed before using it. This will avoid potential crashes and the week reference let's the activity get garbage collected if needed.

Threads are internally used inside AsyncTasks and are handled in an intelligent manner via piling etc by the AsyncTask. If you do use it on your own, you'll be responsible for the clean up and the pooling and all for efficiency. Also this way does not have the easy access to UI thread like the inbuilt methods in AsyncTasks

There are plenty of options available for background tasks like services, intent services, loaders, job scheduler etc. It really depends on how well you understand and use these and how they fit according to your logic. There's no one correct way.

There are plenty of libraries which also help with all this like volley, rx-java and many more.

I personally use pretty much every tool available as and when needed and as and when they fit. Happy coding :)